# Mistakes in forms' position calculations in Delphi

Tags: forms, delphi, vcl

I have stuck with small problem.
Imagine two things: form, that should be covered - Cover-Form; and forms that will cover Cover-Form - Tiles.
My main goal is to cover my Cover-Form with Tiles. So it will looks like the tiles. I illustrate this idea with image below
[image]
Yellow color is a Cover-Form, brown forms - Tiles. On this image you can see that forms are positioned too close each other - there is no free space between them. That's what I need.
But when I try to reach the same effect, I just get non-satisfying result. It is presented on picture below
[image]
Second image has an offset after the last tile. It is happens because of different size of form. I don't know exactly what width my Cover-Form will have. I simply divide the whole width of Cover-Form into three parts. But if Cover-Form has width, for example, 173  pixels, each of my Tiles will have width equal 173/3=57.6 pixels, that will be round to 58, but 58*3=174 and it is bad.

Code below runs situation as on second image.

```
type
  TTileArray = Array of Array of TPoint;

// This routine comes here from David's answer below and were changed by me
procedure EvenlySpacedTiles(PixelCountH, PixelCountV, TileCount: Integer; var ArrayOut: TTileArray);
var
  X: Integer;
  Y: Integer;
  OldH: Integer;
  OldV: Integer;
  OldCount: Integer;
  OldCount1: Integer;
  TempInt: Integer;
begin
  if (PixelCountH) or (PixelCountV) or(TileCount) = 0 then
    Exit;

  OldH := PixelCountH;
  OldCount1 := TileCount;
  for X:=Low(ArrayOut) to High(ArrayOut) do
    begin
      OldV := PixelCountV;
      OldCount := TileCount;

      TempInt := OldH div OldCount1;
      Dec(OldH, TempInt);
      Dec(OldCount1);
      for Y:=Low(ArrayOut) to High(ArrayOut) do
        begin
          ArrayOut[X, Y] := Point(TempInt, OldV div OldCount);
          Dec(OldV, ArrayOut[X, Y].Y);
          Dec(OldCount);
        end;
    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  F: TForm;
  P: TForm;
  Delta: Integer;
  PrevLeft: Integer;
  PrevTop: Integer;
  X:Integer;
  Y: Integer;
  Arr: TTileArray;
  IncLeft: Integer;
begin
  Delta := 3;

  F := TForm.Create(Application);
  F.BorderStyle := Forms.bsNone;
  F.SetBounds(0, 0, 173, 115);
  F.Position := poDesktopCenter;
  F.Color := $11DFEE;
  F.Show;

  SetLength(Arr, Delta, Delta);
  EvenlySpacedTiles(F.Width, F.Height, Delta, Arr);
  PrevLeft := F.Left;
  PrevTop := F.Top;
  IncLeft := 0;
  for X:=Low(Arr) to High(Arr) do
    begin
      PrevTop := F.Top;
      Inc(PrevLeft, IncLeft);
      for Y:=Low(Arr) to High(Arr) do
        begin
          P := TForm.Create(Application);
          P.FormStyle := fsStayOnTop;
          P.BorderStyle := Forms.bsNone;
          P.Color := Random($FFFFFF);//clSkyBlue;
          P.Show;
          P.Width := Arr[X, Y].X;
          P.Height := Arr[X, Y].Y;
          P.Left := PrevLeft;
          P.Top := PrevTop;
          P.Canvas.Rectangle(P.ClientRect);
          Inc(PrevTop, Arr[X, Y].y);
          IncLeft := Arr[X, Y].X;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

So there is my question: how can I adjust width of all tiles (3 per row) independently of cover form's width?

Thanks in advance.

**Edited**

**P.S.**
I modified some parts of code above. Now it works perfectly even with extremely small and large Cover-Form width - from 67 px. to 1237 px.
Of course there is a way to improve this code, but the main goal is achieved.
I think I will able to finish vertical Tiles placing tomorrow and publish this part there.
In many ways the comment by David gives me an idea how to do this. Thank you, David!

**P.S.S.**
I have read David's first comment diagonally, so I update code to work in another way, but the result still not good. You can see it on the picture below.
The first Tile has 57 px. width; the second one - 59 px.; the third Tile - only 31 px.
I just can't get how to place Tiles correctly using an algorithm suggested in David's comment.
[image]

**P.S.S.S.**
And again there is no result.
[image]
Right red line demonstrates a big size of the last tile. Each tile has width 58 px.
David wrote this:

> 173/3=58. 173-58=115. 115/2=58. 115-58=57. 57/1=57

I am able to calculate it in real life, but I am not able to implement it in the code.
Source code is updated.

**P.S.S.S.S.**
David's procedure doesn't do what it should do. Picture below illustrates it.
[image]
There are a gap between the first and the second Tile, and red line on the right side as on previous picture.

**P.S.S.S.S.S.**
Well, at this time the first part of my task is accomplished. The second one - is adding more tiles, but I don't sure if I really need them. And I am thankful for this to [David Heffernan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505088/david-heffernan)!! He spend so much time to explain me some things and I don't know how to say him more than simlply 'Thank you very much'. I am afraid, I am able just increase his reputation and accept his post as an answer. It really does the job!
On picture we can see the result I needed
[image]

**P.S.S.S.S.S.S.**
I have updated source code, so it can place tile and vertically too.
[image]

Comment: 173 is not exactly divisible by 3. Ergo, you cannot use the same width for each column. Instead do it like this. Start with Npx pixels.  Divide by Ncol, round. Use that value for column 0. Subtract that value from Npx and now divide by Ncol-1. Round that value and use for column 1. Repeat until you have exhausted the pixels and columns.

Comment: Also, unless there is a good reason you left out for the sake of brevity, you would not implement each tile to be a separate form. Use shapes, or something else more fitting, instead.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, you mean the next situation, right? Suppose, I have Cover-Form with width 173 pixels. I know that I should place three Tiles per row, so I divide 173 / 3 = 57. This is a width of each Tile. Then I multiply 3 Tiles to 57 and get 171. I know that 171 is less than 173, and according to this fact I should do this: 173 - 171 = 2. This is a size place after the last Tile that presented on the second image, so I just increase width of the last TIle to fully fit Cover-Form. What do you think about this method?

Comment: @DNR, unfortunately, shapes is not a good solution.

Comment: No. Do it exactly the way I described. No mulitplications needed. You just have a stock of pixels to consume, and for each column consume them as evenly as possible. Eventually you will have nothing left to consume.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I have read your first comment again and change code. But it still doesn't work correctly. Could you point me where I did something wrong?

Comment: 173/3=58. 173-58=115. 115/2=58. 115-58=57. 57/1=57.

Comment: I cannot see that your code is making the suggested steps. The first tile is calculated "by hand", why? Try with ONE loop starting with NCols downto 1. Better not use DIV but round(Width/n). I am not at home so i can not provide some code, sorry...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I have tried to do it as you describe it, but with no success. Is it really could be reached via iteration cycle?

Comment: @Andreas, I have updated the source code and replace some Integers with Real, but the result is not clean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a simple algorithm like this:

```
function EvenlySpacedColumns(PixelCount, ColumnCount: Integer): TArray<Integer>;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Assert(PixelCount>0);
  Assert(ColumnCount>0);
  SetLength(Result, ColumnCount);
  for i := low(Result) to high(Result) do begin
    Result[i] := PixelCount div ColumnCount;
    dec(PixelCount, Result[i]);
    dec(ColumnCount);
  end;
end;
```

Here I use `div` which in effect uses division followed by truncation. But you could equally use `Round(PixelCount / ColumnCount)` if you would prefer. It's somewhat arbitrary so I personally would opt for integer arithmetic on the grounds that one should avoid floating point arithmetic if it is not necessary.

Comment: this is a nice piece of code, but it doesn't work. Maybe I did something wrong? Please, see my question again, I added some info.

Comment: The code works fine. You are using it incorrectly. `EvenlySpacedColumns(173, 3)` yields `(57, 58, 58)`. The sum of those three values is `173`. How you fit that into your code is your problem. I urge you to try harder. You appear to have stopped thinking about your problem.

Comment: Ask yourself what `P.SetBounds(F.Left + Arr[i] * i, F.Top, Arr[i], Round(h))` is doing. Why oh why are you using `Arr[i] * i`?!!! For sure I could write your code for you, but what would be the point of that. Don't give up. Don't declare that "my code does not work". The problem is with you. Answer to be found in the mirror. Very easy to demonstrate that the code I presented does what is intended. Now you just need to work out how to lay out your controls correctly. Think!

Comment: I use `Arr[i] * i` to offset each Tile. How else I can place them one by one, assuming that each Tile is one  form? Even if I erase this `* i`, Tiles are not placed correctly.

Comment: and yes, your code works perfectly - it fits array. The problem lies in my code, but it is clear as tear.

Comment: Place the first one at `FLeft`, and initialise `PrevLeft` to that value. The next one at `PrevLeft + Arr[0]`, and increment `PrevLeft` by the width, `Arr[0]`. The third one at `PrevLeft + Arr[1]`, incrementing `PrevLeft` by `Arr[1]`. And so on. Try to convert that into a loop. I can do this in my sleep, but I don't really want to write it all out for you. I'd much rather lead you in the right direction. I beg you to think harder before giving up. Being able to convert the algorithms that you understand when written down, into general loops is a vital skill.

Comment: alright I got it. I will do my best to realise that! :)

Comment: Yes! I did it! I will accept your post as an answer. Thank you, David! See my first post to get more info

Comment: Yep, you got it just fine. That's a pattern that you can use over and over and over again.